# how to add a screen when the screen is off like the default alarm screen when the alarm ring with flutter

Tags: flutter, alarm

[image: once the alarm ring and the phone display will be off then open an alarm screen in the default alarm app. I want to open an alarm screen when the phone screen is off and locked the phone with flutter. also if anyone can solve it in android java. so please put your answer. Thank you so much.]

how to add a screen when the screen is off like the default alarm screen when the alarm ring with flutter.

Comment: once the alarm ring and the phone display will be off then open an alarm screen in the default alarm app. I want to open an alarm screen when the phone screen is off and locked the phone with flutter. also if anyone can solve it in android java. so please put your answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

These screens are actually notifications with full screen intent

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications

This package support full screen intent.

Comment: I need to open a screen when the phone is in lock mode and also screen off as an alarm remember.

Comment: Yeah full screen intent should be able to handle this

Comment: yes, it's possible. but if you can send code then better to understand. can you tell me how to dynamically screen on when screen off? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overlay screen on the lock screen and turn on Screen;

I get only java code for android ;

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

for MainActivity.java

```
 public void overlayScreen(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
         Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1)
     {
        setShowWhenLocked(true);
        setTurnScreenOn(true);
        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        if(keyguardManager!=null)
            keyguardManager.requestDismissKeyguard(this, null);
    }
    else
    {
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    }
}
```

And Add this; which activity do you want to show over lock screen;
for OverlyActivity.java

```
void fullScreen(){
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
   }
```

Both functions call from onCreate method;